# Disable registration functionality for sub-domain in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, multi-sites, domain-access, subsites

I am using `Domain access` module for my multi-site creation and using common database for both the site:

```
1. example1.com (Default domain)
2. example2.com (sub domain)
```

I want default registration functionality for `default domain (example1.com)`, but don't want this functionality on `sub domain (example2.com)`.

If I configure this registration functionality only for Administrators from admin section (`Home » Administration » Configuration » People`) from `default domain (example1.com)` look like below screenshot:

[image]

Then this will be applicable for both `example1.com` and `example2.com`, as I am using common database and common tables for both the sites.

So can anyone please guide me how can I disable the `Registration` functionality for `sub domain (example2.com)` and use this same for `default domain (example1.com)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917630) (to a 'similar' question posted 'a bit before' this question ...), this is a possible answer to this question (= quote from that question):

**= = = Start = = =**

As far as I know you can have different variables per domain (Because the Registration option is a variable) using the latest [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module (currently 7.x-3.11 from 2014-Mar-02). It can be done with a submodule named **Domain Settings**. Enable it if haven't done yet.

If for any reason does not work for you I would suggest to use the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module to handle variables for each domain.

**= = = Stop = = =**